# Automatically avoid the legend

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

In Octave I make a graph using:

```
x = 1:0.1:8.4;
y = x;
plot(x, y, ';Some line;');
```

and get

[image]

Perfect! However, if I use:

```
x = 1:0.1:8.4;
y = sin(x);
plot(x, y, ';Some line;');
```

I get

[image]

Is there a way to automatically adjust the x and y limits such that the plotted line doesn't go inside the legend region. Note that I don't want to shift the legend location to southeastoutside or anything! I want something so that the first graph will remain as it is, but the second graph will increase the max ylim or something **automatically** since I have a lot of graphs to make automatically.

Is this possible? Thanks for the help.

EDIT: Checking the maximum value of y and adjusting the ylim accordingly is a possible solution, but is there a cleaner solution? Like a flag or something so that Octave automatically handles the details?

Comment: This won't be a perfect solution, but a workaround. Just rescale the y-axis to 110%. Meaning:1. find the maximum and minimum of y-axis  2. Rescale your y-axis from [min to max] to [min to min+(max-min)*1.1]

Comment: In matlab you could use `legend('Some line', 'Location','Best');`. But "best" location is not supported in Octave.

Comment: What about placing the legend on the outside of the plot?

Answer (score 1):

So as a written solution you could try this code:

```
y_min=min(y);
y_max=y_min+(max(y)-y_min)*1.1;
x_min=min(x);
x_max=max(x);
plot(x, y, ';Some line;');
axis([x_min x_max y_min y_max])
```

You may play around with the factor(`1.1`) and if you want to check rather if the plot would overlap with the legend before shifting it, you could define yourself your area for the legend and check with an if-case, if the plot enters the area or not:

```
y_min= min(y);
y_max= y_min + (max(y)-y_min)*1.1;
x_min=min(x);
x_max=max(x);
x_legend = floor(numel(x)*0.8);
plot(x, y);
for k=x_legend:1:numel(x)
   if y(k)>max(y)-(max(y)-min(y))*0.1
      axis([x_min x_max y_min y_max])
      break
   end
end
```

Here you can modify the 3 double values: `1.1`, `0.8` and `0.1`. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it can be simpler than

```
delta = 1.1*minmax(x);
plot(x, y, ';Some line;');
axis([minmax(x) minmax(y)+[-delta,delta]]);
```